# How to update selectize input from an external click multiple times in shiny R

Tags: r, shiny

I have been trying to select multiple district from my leaflet map, and update the select input box, subsequently the Go button leads the user to a new tab, showing the information about the districts selected.
In short, I need to have my Map to respond to Multi Select, or store the cache of our previous clicks somewhere, so that the selectize input do not get re initiated each time we click.

Attaching my code.

```
library(shiny)
library(rgdal)
library(leaflet)
library(raster)
library(tmap)
library(shinyjs)

India <- getData("GADM", country = "India", level = 2)
wb <- subset(India, NAME_1 == "West Bengal")

#making a dummy dataframe x

x<-data.frame(wb$NAME_2,wb$ID_2)
KPI<-1:20
x<-cbind(x,KPI)

y<-vector()
edit<-NULL
ui <-fluidPage(
  #use shinyjs
  #plotOutput("shpPlot"),
  leafletOutput("Mapp"),
  selectizeInput("indistrict1","select",choices=wb$NAME_2, multiple=TRUE, 
                 options = list(maxItems = 3)),

  tabsetPanel(id = "inTabset",
              tabPanel("tab_1",actionButton("Button1", "Go")),
              tabPanel("tab_2",actionButton("Button2", "Back" ), tableOutput("q"))
  )
  #tableOutput("my_table")
) 

server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$Mapp<-renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>% addPolygons(data = wb, highlightOptions = 
                                highlightOptions(color = "red", weight = 3, bringToFront = TRUE), layerId = 
                                wb$ID_2)
  })

  #Go Button Work
  observeEvent(input$Button1,{
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "inTabset", selected = "tab_2")
  })

  observeEvent(input$Button2,{
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "inTabset", selected = "tab_1")
  })

  #click event work
  data<- reactiveValues(clicked = NULL)
  z<-reactive({
    df <- data.frame(x)
    colnames(df) <- c("district","id","kpi")
    df
  })

  observeEvent(input$Mapp_shape_click,{
    data$clicked <- input$Mapp_shape_click
    y<-subset(z(), id == data$clicked$id)

    edit<-unique(as.character(y$district))

    updateSelectizeInput(session, "indistrict1",
                         label = "select",
                         choices = c(unique(as.character(y$district)),"All 
                                     Districts"),
                         selected = edit,
                         options = list(maxItems = 3),
                         server = TRUE
                         )
  })

  observeEvent(input$indistrict1,{
    output$q<-renderTable({
      subset(z(), district %in% input$indistrict1)
    })
  })  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui,server = server)
```

Comment: You have the `observeEvent(input$Mapp_shape_click,{..` twice in your code? I think you can remove one. and just for clarity.. You want the leaflet map to store the clicked shapefile, so you can click several shapes and the selected should show in the table then?

Comment: Yes, that was uploaded by mistake, and yes that is exactly what we want, we want the leaflet map to store the id of the clicked shapes and return the information of the selected shapes in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Thats just a start, but it might be helpful for you.

For now it only listens to clicks in the leaflet map, but the clicked shape-IDs are stored, so you can click several shapefiles, which will be highlighted in the map and shown in the table.
But removing clicked shapefiles is missing (By clicking again on the shapefile). Selecting shapefiles over the selectInput also does not work for now, the selectInput only gets updated with the clicked shapefiles.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(raster)
library(DT)

India <- getData("GADM", country = "India", level = 2)
wb <- subset(India, NAME_1 == "West Bengal")

ui <- {fluidPage(
  uiOutput("raumselect"),
  leafletOutput("map"),
  DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")
)}


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  indiashape <- reactiveValues(geom = wb)
  click_list <- reactiveValues(ids = vector())
  selectedLines <- reactiveValues(geom = NULL)

  output$raumselect <- renderUI({
    click <- input$map_shape_click
    sel_lines_name <- as.character(indiashape$geom[as.character(
      indiashape$geom$OBJECTID) %in% click_list$ids, ]$NAME_2)

    selectInput("nameslanes", choices = wb$NAME_2,
                selected = sel_lines_name,
                label = "Select a Line Segment:", multiple = T)
  })

  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    mapl <- leaflet(options = leafletOptions(doubleClickZoom= FALSE)) %>% 
      addTiles() %>% 
      addPolylines(data = indiashape$geom,
                   layerId = as.character(indiashape$geom$OBJECTID),
                   group = indiashape$geom$TYPE_2,
                   color = "blue",
                   highlightOptions = highlightOptions(color="red", weight = 10, bringToFront = T, opacity = 1))        
    mapl
  })

  observeEvent(input$map_shape_click, {
    click <- input$map_shape_click
    proxy <- leafletProxy("map")

    click_list$ids <- c(click_list$ids, click$id)

    sel_lines <- indiashape$geom[as.character(indiashape$geom$OBJECTID) %in% click_list$ids, ]

    proxy %>% addPolylines(data = sel_lines, 
                           layerId = as.character(sel_lines@data$osm_id), 
                           color="red", weight=5,opacity=1)
    selectedLines$geom <- sel_lines
  })

  output$mytable <- DT::renderDataTable({
    req(selectedLines$geom)

    if (!is.null(selectedLines$geom)) {
      sel_lines <- selectedLines$geom
      datafr <- as.data.frame(cbind(
        as.numeric(sel_lines$OBJECTID),
        as.character(sel_lines$NAME_2)
      ))
    }
    colnames(datafr) <- c("OBJECTID", "Name")
    datatable(data = datafr, rownames = T)
  })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```